# filter timestamp column in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, where-clause

I have a table with a Timestamp column which I need to filter after '2020-08-26', but every solution won't work

```
RUN_TIME
2020-07-22 04:22:07
2020-07-22 04:34:07
2020-07-22 04:45:07
2020-07-22 04:50:07
2020-07-22 04:55:08
```

I tried the below queries:

`WHERE CAST (RUN_DATE AS DATE)  >= TO_DATE('2020-08-26',  'yyyy-mm-dd')`

`WHERE to_date(RUN_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') >=  to_date('26-08-2020 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')`

`WHERE RUN_DATE >= TO_TIMESTAMP('26-08-2020 23:59:59')`

Comment: Is the data type `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TIMESTAMP` literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  run_time >= TIMESTAMP '2020-08-27 00:00:00';
```

or, use a `DATE` literal:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  run_time >= DATE '2020-08-27';
```

or, use `TO_TIMESTAMP` with a format model:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  run_time >= TO_TIMESTAMP( '2020-08-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD' );
```

or, use `TO_DATE` with a format model:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  run_time >= TO_DATE( '2020-08-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD' );
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( run_time TIMESTAMP(6) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( run_time )
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22 04:22:07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22 04:34:07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22 04:45:07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22 04:50:07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-07-22 04:55:08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-26 23:59:59.999999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-27 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

> ```
> | RUN_TIME                  |
> | :------------------------ |
> | 27-AUG-20 00.00.00.000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9a2ff72a6b462349df60fcb7a904e1b)*

Comment: I don't know where is the problem from my side, but every solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader As I commented on the question, what is the exact data type of the column?

Comment: it's a Timestamp

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader `TIMESTAMP`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`?

Comment: No it's ```TIMESTAMP``` Only

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
where run_date >= date '2020-08-26'
```

That's direct filtering against a `date` literal.

`run_date` is a `timestamp` already, so you should not attempt to convert it. Also, `to_timestamp()` takes a second argument, which specifies the format of the string; without it, it defaults to the `nls_timestamp_format` of your session (or database), which may not be what you expect

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader: that would be suprising. Are you able to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the problem?